# More robust expression in join clause of data.table join?

Tags: r, join, data.table

Is it possible for the `on` clause of a `data.table` join to support more involved expressions than (in)equalities? For example, if I try to execute

```
B[A,on=.(name = toupper(name))]
```

or

```
B[A,on=.(year = year(date))]
```

I receive the error message

> Error in `[.data.table`(B, A, on = .(name = toupper(name))) : 
>     Column(s) [toupper(name)] not found in i

`data.table` seems to be looking for a column whose name is the unevaluated expression rather than evaluating the expression. Replacing `name = toupper(name)` with something like `name = eval(quote(toupper(name)))` doesn't seem to help either.

I can always work around this by adding an extra column to one or both of the inputs (a la `name_upper := toupper(name)` in this case) and then removing the unneeded column after the join, but this is clunky and cumbersome.

Is it possible to achieve an analogue of SQL join functionality here?

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like this:

**sample data**

```
DT <- data.table( id = 1:3, name = c("John", "JOHN", "Steve"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

> ```
>    id  name
> 1:  1  John
> 2:  2  JOHN
> 3:  3 Steve
> ```

**code**

```
DT[copy(DT)[, NAME := toupper(name)], id2 := i.id, on = .(name = NAME)][]
```

**output**

> ```
>    id  name id2
> 1:  1  John  NA
> 2:  2  JOHN   2
> 3:  3 Steve  NA
> ```